# MongoDB automatic document relation mapping C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, object-relational-model

Are there any frameworks out there for MongoDB in C# that can automatically map Document Relations? I'm now talking about a model or "schema" that is purely defined by documents themselves and not by objects in .Net or any other external schema for that matter.

Think dynamic objects / bsondocuments that can automatically lazy-load relations between other documents.

I have several ideas how to solve this myself however if there already exist any frameworks or perhaps BsonDocument extensions (how I intended to solve this myself) this would lessen the need to add complexity to the project I'm working at itself.

Answer (score 1):

The question is largely off-topic ('are there frameworks'), but I'd like to challenge the idea in itself:

> this would lessen the need to add complexity to the project I'm working at itself.

I think it would merely *hide* complexity by moving it to a part of the code that knows nothing about your functional or non-functional requirements. Combined with a database that has no constraints except unique that doesn't sound like a good idea.

I'd recommend to stay away from lazy loading as an almost general rule, because it makes it impossible to tell whether

- an operation is super costly (database call) or a mere memory lookup
- the properties' state will be fetched on access, or is cached, thus hiding *the* key aspect of serialization from the user.

In other words: I'd stay away from the idea, or use something like EF with whatever database for it. If you don't care about your serialization, use a well-tested commonplace solution.